# Java FormData Request is blank

Tags: java, rest, request

I am calling one third party request and in that i have to send form data using java:

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.145.0.17:5000/callDay");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty(
                    "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=--******");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter httpRequestBodyWriter =
                    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));


            httpRequestBodyWriter.write("\n\n--******\n");
            httpRequestBodyWriter.write("Content-Disposition: form-data;"
                    + "name=\"user_id\""
                    + "\n Admin");

            httpRequestBodyWriter.write("\n\n--******\n");
            httpRequestBodyWriter.write("Content-Disposition: form-data;"
                    + "name=\"abc\";"
                    + "filename=\"abc\""
                    + "\nContent-Type: \n\n");
            httpRequestBodyWriter.write("\n\n--******\n");
            httpRequestBodyWriter.write("Content-Disposition: form-data;"
                    + "name=\"ouput_path\""
                    + "\n dc");

            httpRequestBodyWriter.flush();

            os.write(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(nbPath)));


            os.flush();

            // Mark the end of the multipart http request
            httpRequestBodyWriter.write("\n--******--\n");
            httpRequestBodyWriter.flush();

            os.close();
            httpRequestBodyWriter.close();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
```

and this request is of python endpoint but when python try to read request from data it is always getting blank data. why it is getting blank data?

sorry for my english. please help me out.